# Would the big-omega of a variable that is big-O of a second variable be the big-omega of that second variable?

Tags: complexity-theory

If I had a variable x which I knew was O(y), and I knew that a third variable t is big-omega(x), would it be true that t is big-omega(y)?

Comment: If `x <= y` and `t >= x` does it follow that `t >= y`?

Comment: Complexity is a property of functions, not variables

Answer (score 0):

No. First of all, let's replace all occurrences of "variable" by function to make the question meaningful. Then consider the following counterexample:

```
x(n) = n
y(n) = n^2
t(n) = n
```

These assignments satisfy the antecedent, but not the consequence.